# How to solve CORS problems between OpenLayers v6.14.1 and GeoServer 2.20.2 in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, tomcat, cors, openlayers, geoserver

I'm trying to get WMS layer as a tile layer via "tileLoadFunction" in OL v6.14.1 in reactjs but when I run below code I will get CORS error message:

```
  map.addLayer(
      new TileLayer({
        source:new TileWMS({
          url:`http://194.105.111.10:8080/geoserver/${selectedLayer[i].datastore}/wms`,
          visible:true,
          projection:'EPSG:4326',
          params:{'LAYERS':layerName,'TILED': true},
          serverType:'geoserver',
          tileLoadFunction:function(image, src) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.open('GET', src);
           
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://194.105.111.10:3000")
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer f5711f9d-aa2d-4067-p5a9-af913vd16a21');
          xhr.onload = function() {
                var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
                image.getImage().onload = function() {
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
                    
      };
      image.getImage().src = objectURL;
      };
      xhr.send();
      },
                
      }),
      name:`${selectedLayer[i].name}`
    }))
```

---

```
GET http://194.105.111.10:8080/geoserver/higU1EU8kM6eJtKaHg14USMyTsQSOpP6/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=higU1EU8kM6eJtKaHg14USMyTsQSOpP6%3Acontour_line&TILED=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&BBOX=22.5%2C67.5%2C33.75%2C78.75 net::ERR_FAILED
```

---

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://194.105.111.10:8080/geoserver/higU1EU8kM6eJtKaHg14USMyTsQSOpP6/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=higU1EU8kM6eJtKaHg14USMyTsQSOpP6%3Acemetery_shape&TILED=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&BBOX=22.5%2C67.5%2C33.75%2C78.75' 
from origin 'http://194.105.111.10:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I did enable CORS in GeoServer web.xml already, I did enable CORS in Tomcat web.xml also, Furthermore this is my CORS setting in nodejs for expressjs and nodejs routers:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

 
  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
  
app.use(cors({
  "origin": "http://194.105.111.10:3000",
  "credentials":true,
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}))
```

my current CORS setting for GeoServer in /opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
  <!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS in Tomcat. Do not forget the> -->
    <filter>
      <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
</filter>

    
my current CORS setting in Tomcat9.0.58 /opt/tomcat/conf/web.xml

<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Although I did enable all CORS configuration in Tomcat and GeoServer and Backend(nodejs) , I will get CORS ERROR

I'm running Reactjs on http://194.105.111.10:3000
my nodejs is running on http://194.105.111.10:3001
I am editing code on remote server (address 194.105.111.10) by vscode

My Laptop OS is LMDE v5
Server Info:
OS: Debian 11 x64,
Nodejs: 16.x,
React 17.x,
Tomcat 9.0.58,
Java v8,
GeoServer 2.20.2,

Authentication method
[image]

before I want to add WMS layer to map I created  a svg link as a layer preview in layers list table:

I did that by axios in backend(nodejs), below code give me a svg image link I will use that in table layer in firnt-end(Reactjs) (*I think sometime this method cause to user login to geoserver in background)* :

```
await axios({
      method:"GET",
      url:`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/${geoName}/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&layers=${geoName}:${layerName}&srs=EPSG:4326`,
     
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,

      headers:{
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"http://194.105.111.10:3000",
        'Content-Type':'application/xml',
        'Accept':'application/xml',
     
      },
      auth:{
        username:  username,
        password: geopass,
      },

    }).then((response)=>{
    // console.log('response get Capabilities ', response.data)
    try{
      parseString(response.data,async function(err,result){
    //  console.log('capabilities result ',result["WMS_Capabilities"].Capability[0].Layer[0].Layer)
        const getLayerCapability =result["WMS_Capabilities"].Capability[0].Layer[0].Layer
    // console.log('getLayerCapability',getLayerCapability)
      await getLayerCapability.forEach(element=>{
        // log('element ', element)
         if(element.Name.includes(layerName)){
          // log('element BoundingBox ', element.BoundingBox[1]["$"])
         Object.assign(bbox,element.BoundingBox[1]["$"])
      
       
         }
        
       })
        
      })
    }catch(error){
      console.error('getSvgLayers Error ', error)
    }
     
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.error('error ', error)
    })

// //
      const url=`http://194.105.111.10:8080/geoserver/${geoName}/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=${geoName}:${layerName}&bbox=${bbox.minx},${bbox.miny},${bbox.maxx},${bbox.maxy}&width=768&height=768&srs=${bbox.CRS}&styles=&format=image/svg&authkey=${authkey}`
      return url
```

I should mention I connected Reactjs to Nodejs via proxy in Reacjs package.json
"proxy":"http://194.105.111.10:3001"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42024918/6072570 Try this

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Edge stable version on LMDE 5, when I want to add authorization header in tileloadfuntion I will get CORS error, I think if I find a way for login to GeoServer, this issue will be solve

Answer (score -1):

Have you solve this problem? As I see from your config there is one mistake.
You can't use * for origins when credentials support is true.
You can check advanced configuration here:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html